# Problems with using a SQLalchemy Declared Base Object when created from Dictionary

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have simple classes mapped to python dictionies, WHen trying to add them to an in memory SQLite Db using SQLalchemy i get troubles running filtered queries.
As the objects were already in dicts I added a class method to my mapped objects, that could create an instance of the mapped class from the dict.
here is the set up:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker


Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    mailbox = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dict):
        cls.mailbox = dict["mailbox"]
        cls.uid = dict["uid"]
        cls.name = dict["name"]
        return cls(mailbox=cls.mailbox,
                       uid=cls.uid,
                      name=cls.name)
```

The classmethod of User returns the User class. All the other set up is pretty normal.

For demonstration i created two lists, one of mapped User objects. One of dictionaries with User Data. Despite the types, the info inside each is identical.

```
def dict_user_list():
    return [{'mailbox':"inbox", 'uid':1, 'name':"tim"},
            {'mailbox':"inbox", 'uid':2, 'name':"mark"},
            {'mailbox':"inbox", 'uid':3, 'name':"susan"},
            {'mailbox':"mybox", 'uid':1, 'name':"geoff"},
            {'mailbox':"mybox", 'uid':2, 'name':"kim"},
            {'mailbox':"mybox", 'uid':3, 'name':"trev"},
            {'mailbox':"mybox", 'uid':4, 'name':"rick"}]

def user_list():
    return [User(mailbox="inbox", uid=1, name="tim"),
            User(mailbox="inbox", uid=2, name="mark"),
            User(mailbox="inbox", uid=3, name="susan"),
            User(mailbox="mybox", uid=1, name="geoff"),
            User(mailbox="mybox", uid=2, name="kim"),
            User(mailbox="mybox", uid=3, name="trev"),
            User(mailbox="mybox", uid=4, name="rick")]
```

Here is the rest of the setup:

```
ENGINE = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.create_all(ENGINE)
Base.metadata.bind = ENGINE

session_maker = sessionmaker()

session = session_maker()
```

Now if i add the Users via the .from_dict class method:

```
session.add_all([User.from_dict(user) for user in dict_user_list()])
```

Then run a query and filter:

```
query = session.query(User)
print("inbox filter: ", query.filter(User.mailbox == 'inbox').count())
print("mybox filter: ", query.filter(User.mailbox == 'mybox').count())
print("inbox filter_by: ", query.filter_by(mailbox='inbox').count())
print("mybox filter_by: ", query.filter_by(mailbox='mybox').count())
```

The output is:

```
inbox filter:  0
mybox filter:  7
inbox filter_by:  0
mybox filter_by:  7
```

This is wrong. But i can get the correct answers by using text()

```
print("inbox filter: ", query.filter(text('Users.mailbox = "inbox"')).count()) 
print("mybox filter: ", query.filter(text('Users.mailbox = "mybox"')).count())
```

The output gives the correct results:

```
inbox filter:  3
mybox filter:  4
```

If I change my .add_all() argument to create my instances via User(....):

```
session.add_all([user for user in user_list()])
```

Then run mu queries and filters again without using text():

```
query = session.query(User)
print("inbox filter: ", query.filter(User.mailbox == 'inbox').count())
print("mybox filter: ", query.filter(User.mailbox == 'mybox').count())
print("inbox filter_by: ", query.filter_by(mailbox='inbox').count())
print("mybox filter_by: ", query.filter_by(mailbox='mybox').count())
```

The output is correct:

```
inbox filter:  3
mybox filter:  4
inbox filter_by:  3
mybox filter_by:  4
```

Obviously the solution is not to invoke instances of my mapped class from a dict. But As i spend so long trying to work out what was going on here I would love to know what is going on here, Is it a lack of understanding of SQLalchemy? a lack of understanding of classmethods? or just a lack of understanding of python in general?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but why are you assigning the contents of the dictionary to attributes of `cls`? That would overwrite the `Column`s in the class declaration, right? What happens if you remove those three lines?

Comment: Does this approach not return an instance of the class?

Comment: It does, but it also changes the class itself. I think `return cls(mailbox=dict["mailbox"], uid=dict["uid"], name=dict["name"])` is all that is necessary

Comment: Oh yes. That's exactly right. That solved the problem. So i guess, the last call to .from_dict() was setting the class atrubutes. Then the query was accessing these and getting the incorrect values?

Comment: That's good! And yeah, whatever `.from_dict()` was called with last would determine `User.mailbox`, etc. I suspect the issue of querying comes from the fact that SQLAlchemy knows it can set a value on an instance when the class has a `Column` for that name/attribute. But since they were being overwritten, they weren't `Column`s anymore, and SQLAlchemy ignored them